# Display custom third party html element inside a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to show a custom HTML modal that is returned from a third-party library inside a functional React component.

This is the function that should load the modal, which is being called inside useEffect:

```js
const modalRef = useRef()
   
const loadScript = async () => {
    // custom script loader 
    const loader = new ScriptLoader({
      src: 'checkout.reepay.com/checkout.js',
      global: 'Reepay',
    })
    
    await loader.load()

    // flag for displaying the div
    setLoaded(true)

    // Reepay.ModalCheckout(sessionId) should open a modal
    modalRef.current.innerHTML = new window.Reepay.ModalCheckout(sessionId)
}
```

In my return:

```js
return loaded ? <div ref={modalRef}></div> : <></>
```

When I try to display the component I just get a [Object object] inside the div. I don't know if using refs is the way to go, I'm a beginner and I didn't really understand how to integrate third-party code inside React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their documentation (https://docs.reepay.com/reference#overlay-checkout), it seems that instance of `Reepay.ModalCheckout` is an object, not HTML:

```
// Step 1: Initialize
var rp = new Reepay.ModalCheckout();  // No session id given

// ... Backend to backend call ... 

// Step 2: Load the modal 
rp.show(' YOUR SESSION ID HERE ');  // Call the .show function with the session id
```

You do not have to inject it inside of a modal, since it comes with their own modal.

If you really want to inject it into a container, you should be using:

```
var rp = new Reepay.EmbeddedCheckout(' YOUR SESSION ID HERE ', { html_element: 'rp_container' } );
```